# Exclude specific column in rdd map

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, slice, rdd

I have a huge dataset with about 20 columns.
I'm working with rdds in pyspark and need to do something like

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[9], x[:] - x[9]))
```

basically. create a ley value pair such that one of the columns is the key and rest of them are values. I'm unable to slice it in a way that makes sense.

i've tried

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[9], x[:] - x[9]))
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[9], x[:8] + x[10:]))
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[9], list(x[:8].append(x[10:]))))
```

none of it seems to be working. I'm not sure what the right way to do it would be

Comment: why not dataframe?

Comment: @Lamanus... coz the steps further require me to work with rdd.

Answer (score 0):

I would break the problem into steps.

```py
# First we set it up
data = [(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)] # one row
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
rdd.collect()
#[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
```

Next we need a function that pops a value from a tuple and makes it a key.

```py
def key_elem_to_rest(key_index, tup):
  l = list(tup)
  key = l.pop(key_index)
  return {key: tuple(l)}
```

Next up we use it in the `map`

```py
rdd.map(lambda x: key_elem_to_rest(0, x)).collect() # index = 0
#[{1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)}]
rdd.map(lambda x: key_elem_to_rest(5, x)).collect() # index = 5
#[{6: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10)}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[9]).map(lambda x: (x[9], [x[:-1]]))
```

This is checking if the x[9] is not a key and it is making it as a key and rest as value.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out myself.

```
units_rdd1 = units_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[9], list(x[0:9]+x[10:])))
```